# Выбор типа без потери точности c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс вектора:

```
template< int size, typename Type >
class Vector;
```

Есть шаблонный оператор для сложения двух векторов:

```
template< int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType >
Vector<size, ?> operator+( const Vector<size, LeftType>& left, const Vector<size, RightType>& right )
    {...}
```

Который, по задумке, должен работать с любыми типами векторов, лишь бы они были одного размера. Чтобы можно было сложить Vector<3, int> и Vector<3, double>. Но встает вопрос - как определить результирующий тип вектора, чтобы точность не терялась?

Например для int и  double логично было бы выбрать double, для int и float - float, для float и double - double. Как этого можно добиться, не прописывая шаблон для каждого случая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `std::common_type`.

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа. Я объявил класс `Vector`  с минимальными свойствами, чтобы лишь продемонстрировать использование `std::common_type`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template< int size, typename Type >
struct Vector
{
    std::vector<Type> v;
};    

template< int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType >
Vector<size, typename std::common_type<LeftType, RightType>::type> 
operator +( const Vector<size, LeftType>& left, const Vector<size, RightType>& right )
{
    Vector<size, typename std::common_type<LeftType, RightType>::type> v;
    v.v.resize( size );

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) v.v[i] = left.v[i] + right.v[i];

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    Vector<5, int> left = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
    Vector<5, double> right = { { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 } };

    auto v = left + right;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) std::cout << v.v[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5
```

Answer (score 3):

Если есть возможность использовать C++11, то

```
#include<utility>    

template< int size, typename LeftType, typename RightType >
Vector<size, decltype(std::declval<LeftType>() + std::declval<RightType>())> ...
```